# Legacy web application in jsp,servlets to be made i-pad compatible

Tags: ipad, jsp, servlets

Currently we have a web application that's been developed using `jsp` and `servlets`. A new requirement has come to make this application ipad compatible.

1. What is the best way to proceed?
2. Will using jQuery mobile and restructuring all the jsp pages (creating dedicated pages for ipaad) do the trick?
3. Is there any supporting documents already available?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Through my research, what I found is

1)Learn CSS 3 Media queries and restructure the css and html pages to be displayed.

2)The approach is ok, but creating dedicated web pages for i-Pad will increase the size of your web app.

3)Head First Mobile Web is a good reference